# An example of a series $\sum a_n$ that converges conditionally but $\sum a_n^3$ does not converge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Give an example of a series $\sum a_n$ that converges conditionally but $\sum a_n^3$ does not converge conditionally.

I've come up with an example.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]3}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]3}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]3}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]3}+\cdots$.

While the sum of the cubes is

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8\cdot 2}-\frac{1}{8\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{27\cdot 3}-\frac{1}{27\cdot 3}-\frac{1}{27\cdot 3}+\cdots$

Now the series seems to converge to 0, however, I cannot show using an epsilon argument that it does. Also, the sum of the cubes looks like $\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{8}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{15}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{4}+\cdots$, so I can see that it diverges, but likewise, cannot supply this with a rigorous argument.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me with this part.

Comment: $\sum a_n^3$ does not means ?? Does not conditionally convergent OR does not convergent ?

Comment: Assuming the former (otherwise the question is misstated), the Harmonic Series is certainly a counterexample.

Comment: How does the Harmonic series work? The series doesn't converge.

Comment: You mean to require that $\sum a_n^3$ does not converge at all. @Travis meant the alternating harmonic series, of course.

Comment: You would make the example much simpler if you were to use always the $(1,-1/2,-1/2)$ pattern, for all $\sqrt[3]{n}$..

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, thank you, that's (of course) what I meant to write. The minus sign was lost when I opted to write out the term in words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\sum a_n$ converges, prove $\sum a_n^3$ converges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798418/if-sum-a-n-converges-prove-sum-a-n3-converges)

Comment: And of [Show a convergent series $\sum a_n$, but $\sum a_n^p$ is not convergent](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/607293)

Answer (score 1):

Consider , $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $a_n$ is conditionally convergent. But , $a_n^3=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}$ is **NOT** conditionally  convergent ; as it is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Well I upvoted. Anyone who downvoted has some 'splainin to do.

Comment: Unfair! We are looking at divergent cubes... Absolutely convergent examples from conditionally convergent series are trivial.

Comment: This clearly misses the point of the question

Answer (score 1):

Use the simplified example
$$
\frac1{\sqrt[3]2}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]2}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]2}+\frac1{\sqrt[3]3}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]3}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]3}+\frac1{\sqrt[3]4}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]4}-\frac1{2\sqrt[3]4}+…
$$
Then it is easy to see that this series is conditionally convergent, however the third power series is $3/4$ of the harmonic series in one subsequence of the sequence of partial sums and thus not convergent.